# Compose preview doesn't work at all - project needs to be compiled

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I use Android Studio Bumblebee 2021.1.1 Patch 3 built on March 16, 2022

*androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling, androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview, androidx.compose.ui:ui*
are in version `1.2.0-alpha07`

I want to create preview of my composable but I can't create any one. Every time I see error:
"The project needs to be compiled for the preview to be displayed"
I rebuilt, synced project and restarted Android Studio but it doesn't help.
What can be wrong?

My composable for example:

```
@Composable
fun DefaultProfileAvatarBox(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
        .size(60.dp),
    firstLetter: String
) {
    val finalModifier = modifier
        .clip(CircleShape)
        .background(blueAvatarBackground)

    Box(
        modifier = finalModifier
    ) {
        Text(
            text = firstLetter,
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(bottom = 2.dp)
                .align(Alignment.Center),
            fontSize = 32.sp,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.SemiBold,
            color = Color.White,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center
        )
    }
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun DefaultProfileAvatarBoxPreview() {
    DefaultProfileAvatarBox(firstLetter = "K")
}
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue with Bumblebee and I'm pretty sure it started after an update.

Comment: I have the same problem with Android Studio Chipmunk 2021.2.1 Patch 1 and Jetpack Compose 1.2.0. There is no error in Android Studio's event log. I have no clue what the problem is or how to solve it.

Comment: The error does not occur with Android Studio Dolphin 2021.3.1 Beta 5

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem
But when I used the **stable** version of activity-compose **(1.4.0)** !
The problem was solved.

```
dependencies {
// ...
     implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.4.0' 
}
```

Comment: I used the `activity_compose 1.4.0` but still having the error.

Comment: @Tonnie, Try to use stable versions for all dependencies once,
And check which dependency causes the error

Answer (score 0):

Use version `1.1.1` to avoid this.

I hope it helps you.